# How to make mdichild load at the center of mdiparent window

Tags: c#, mdi

HI all,

I have this code in which the window property of making child window load at the center of mdiparent.

```
        Form2 f = new Form2();

        f.MdiParent = this;

        //center screen is working.

        //f.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;

        f.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
```

but instead of making the child window pop at the center it loads at the left side.
Can anyone help me on this.
Please refer the screenshot below.

I have even tried doing the same in vb. Even there i get the same error. I think the property of FormStartPosition.CenterParent is dummy.

[alt text http://img13.imageshack.us/img13/7003/errorprb.jpg](http://img13.imageshack.us/img13/7003/errorprb.jpg)

Answer (score 17):

I experimented a bit with this, and first came to the same solution as Patrick. But I was bugged by the following statement in [the documentation of the `StartPosition` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.startposition.aspx):

> You can also position the form to
>   display in the center of the screen or
>   in the center of its parent form for
>   forms such as multiple-document
>   interface (MDI) child forms.

So, I decided that there must be a way. And there is, though I don't find it all intuitive: set the `StartPosition` to `CenterScreen` (*not* `CenterParent`):

```
MdiChildUI form = new MdiChildUI();
form.MdiParent = this;
form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
form.Show();
```

Of course, you can also set it in the designer instead of in code.

Comment: +1, CenterScreen is the correct method for centering an mdichild in its parent form

Comment: Is there any chance by which we can make the child layout become center of the mdi parent.  I think the property of FormStartPosition.CenterParent is dummy if it cannot make the child in the center of the parent.

Comment: @Srikanth: read my answer again; the provided code will show the mdi child centered in the mdi parent.

Answer (score 6):

Setting start position as center screen works perfect for me.

Answer (score 5):

I tried showing the child with the MDI container form as owner, but caused an exception for me.  You could manually set the location before showing the child as follows:

```
Form2 f = new Form2();
f.MdiParent = this;
f.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
f.Location = new Point((this.ClientSize.Width - f.Width) / 2,
                       (this.ClientSize.Height - f.Height) / 2);
f.Show();
```

EDIT:

```
f.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
```

is the correct way to center an mdichild on its parent form.

Comment: This method has good logic. But this will work with respect to the screen and not the parent container. So it will look bit ackward if the parent and child windows are minimized.

Comment: Is there any chance by which we can make the child layout become center of the mdi parent. I think the property of FormStartPosition.CenterParent is dummy if it cannot make the child in the center of the parent.

Answer (score 0):

A form has an **MdiParent** property and a **Parent** property.

Please notice that an MdiParent **IS NOT** the parent of MdiChild form.

It is, its MdiParent;

So **CenterToParent** Method is meaningless for these types of forms.

You can see the functionality of **CenterToParent** Method when you program for multiple monitors application, or when you host a form inside another form by setting its **Toplevel** property to false, and setting its **Parent** property to another form.

Good Luck,

Aram Afsar